# One or more variables have some issues with their values

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to access environment variables in my project the same way I do it in my other project and I can't.
This is what I have in my projects and it works for one project and doesn't work for the other. Why?

```
pipeline {
  agent { label('builder') }
  environment {
    BRANCH               = env.BRANCH_NAME.replace('/', '-')
    SERVICE              = "some_name"
    IMAGE_TAG            = "${env.BRANCH}-${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
    CI_IMAGE_TAG         = "CI-${env.BRANCH}-${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
  }
}
```

I get an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: One or more variables have some issues with their values: BRANCH
```

Jenkins version: 2.332

Comment: Where is the `BRANCH_NAME` parameter defined?

Comment: This is a global variable. I saw it under JENKINS_HOST/env_vars.html. Maybe it is available only for multi-branch project? https://e.printstacktrace.blog/images/jenkins-env-vars.jpg